# Catch - Blocking the complete loop

Tags: powershell

I am executing a Powershell script to fetch the badpwdcount on each AD domain controller. There are about 50 domain controllers. When running the script, one of the servers cannot be reached. The script should record failed connection attempt and continue. However, the script terminates after the failed connection attempt.

```
Param(
                $BadOption,
                $Samaccountname = "<accountname>"
)
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$result = @()
try {
    $DC = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | select -exp hostname
    $DC1 = $DC -notlike { "<DC Server>", "<DC Server1>" } # skipping few

    foreach ($Domaincontroller in $DC1) {


        $count = Get-ADUser -Identity $Samaccountname -Server $Domaincontroller -Properties badPwdCount | select badPwdCount
        $result += $Domaincontroller + ',' + $count

    }
    #echo $result

}
catch {
    $errmsg = $_.Exception.Message
    $result += $Domaincontroller + ' :' + "Error : " + $errmsg
}

return $result
```

Comment: In your catch block, you could add a `Continue` statement. That may require you to start and end your foreach loop OUTSIDE of the try-catch block.

Comment: As an aside: `$DC -notlike {"<DC Server>","<DC Server1>"}` will not work as expected; you probably meant `$DC -notin "<DC Server>","<DC Server1>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add a test inside the loop to check if the domaincontroller can be reached?

```
# An array of DC hostnames you want to exclude
$Exclude = "<DC Server>","<DC Server1>"

# By setting $ErrorActionPreference to Stop, PowerShell treats all non-terminating errors as terminating.
# This is useful when using try{..} catch{..} blocks.
$oldErrorAction = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

$result = @()
$DC = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty hostname | Where-Object { $Exclude -notcontains $_ }

foreach($Domaincontroller in $DC) {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Domaincontroller -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        try {
            $count  = (Get-ADUser -Identity $Samaccountname -Server $Domaincontroller -Properties badPwdCount).badPwdCount
            $result += "$Domaincontroller, $count"
        }
        catch {
            $errmsg = $_.Exception.Message
            $result += "$Domaincontroller :Error : $errmsg"
        }
    }
    else {
        $result += "$Domaincontroller :Error : Failed connection attempt"
    }
}
# Restore the previous value for the $ErrorActionPreference variable
$ErrorActionPreference = $oldErrorAction

$result
```

Comment: Thank you heaps for your help. I got it this has fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The `Continue` statement should allow you to keep processing after terminating errors in a `Try-Catch` block.

```
$result = @()
$DC = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | select -exp hostname
$DC1 = $DC -notlike {"<DC Server>","<DC Server1>"} # skipping few

foreach($Domaincontroller in $DC1)
{
    try
    {
            $count = Get-ADUser -Identity $Samaccountname -Server $Domaincontroller -Properties badPwdCount | select badPwdCount
            $result += $Domaincontroller + ',' + $count

    }

    catch {
            $errmsg = $_.Exception.Message
            $result += $Domaincontroller + ' :'+ "Error : "+$errmsg
            Continue
    }
}
$result
```

Answer (score 1):

As in this:

```
$result = @()

$DC = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | select -exp hostname
$DC1 = $DC -notlike {"<DC Server>","<DC Server1>"} # skipping few

ForEach($Domaincontroller in $DC1) {
    Write-Host $Domaincontroller
    Try {
        $count = Get-ADUser -Identity $Samaccountname -Server $Domaincontroller -Properties badPwdCount | select badPwdCount
        $result += $Domaincontroller + ',' + $count
    }
    Catch{
        $errmsg = $_.Exception.Message
        $result += $Domaincontroller + ' :'+ "Error : "+$errmsg
    }
}
Return $result
```